# Can't get this simple test class to work

Tags: apex

I have spent almost 8 hours trying to figure out why my test class isn't working but to no avail. I have simplified and de-bulkfifed the test class to insert only 1 record each for the relevant objects and it still doesn't work. My trigger is the culprit and I can't debug why it isn't allowing my test class to run. The issue occurs when my test class tries to create a case.

I fail to understand that why I can't insert a simple case using my test class. Why is my apex trigger isn't allowing it? Any input would be much appreciated!

***Main trigger:***
It  will prevent each user from creating more than certain cases in the current month (Specified by custom setting- MaxCases ). The trigger runs fine and does what it's supposed to do on the UI.

**Trigger**

```
trigger LimitCases on Case (before insert) {

//Extract the custom setting value into a variable
Max_Cases__c maxCase = Max_Cases__c.getInstance('maxcasesetting');
Integer maxNoCases   = Integer.valueof(maxCase.MaxCases__c);

    System.debug('The max no. of cases setting is:' + maxNoCases);

/*1. Create a set of all Owner Id's whose cases are being fed for import
     Also, Add all userIds to a map with 0 number of cases as initial values */

if(maxNoCases!=null) {
Map<Id,Integer> ownerCasesMap = new Map<Id,Integer>();
Set<String> ownerIds = new Set<String>();

    for(Case newCase: Trigger.new) {
            System.debug('Creating a set of Owner Ids');
            ownerIds.add(newCase.OwnerId);
            ownerCasesMap.put(newCase.OwnerId,0);

            }



/*2. Create a user Map just to obtain the Owner Name using their Id
     Salesforce doesn't allow doing Owner.name for some incomprehensible reason! */

       Map<Id,User> userMap = new Map<Id,User>();
       List<User> userM =[SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Id IN: ownerIds];
       for(User ownerUser:userM) {
       userMap.put(ownerUser.Id, ownerUser);
       }


     //3. Use AggregateResults to get a count of all Cases pertaining to the           above owners

System.debug('Creating a list of grouped results[AggregateResults] now');
List<AggregateResult> groupedResults= [SELECT OwnerId , count(Id) FROM Case
                                       WHERE OwnerId IN:ownerIds 
                                       AND CreatedDate= THIS_MONTH     
                                       GROUP BY OwnerId];


//4. Use the previously created Map to store Owner Id and the number of Cases from above

for(AggregateResult countCase: groupedResults) {


System.debug('Entered the AggregateResult For loop');

    if(countCase!=null) {     

    System.debug('Owner Id:' + countCase.get('OwnerId'));
    System.debug('Count is' + countCase.get('expr0'));

    //Map now has key-> Owner Id, value-> Case count
    //This will replace the owners previous put in the Map with new values and not put anything for NULL
    //This way users who didn't create any cases this month are retained in the previously created map

   ownerCasesMap.put((Id)countCase.get('OwnerId'), (Integer)countCase.get('expr0'));
    }
  }


   //Go through every Case being inserted , find the case count from above and compare to maxCases

   for(Case newCase: Trigger.new) {

       System.debug('Entered the main Case Trigger.new!');

       //Get the number of cases associated with the Owner Id of this case    
       Integer numCases  = ownerCasesMap.get(newCase.OwnerId);

       System.debug('Number of Cases created so far by this owner:'+ numCases);

       //Do not allow the user to create a case if the limit is reached
       if(numCases>=maxNoCases) {
       System.debug('Entered the if loop in order to show the error since numCases>=maxNoCases' );
       newCase.addError('Too many cases created this month for user' + ' ' + userMap.get(newCase.OwnerId).Name + '(' + newCase.OwnerId + '):' + ' ' + maxNoCases);
       }                  

           else {
           System.debug('Entered the else loop in order to let the user create the case' );

           ownerCasesMap.put(newCase.OwnerId, ownerCasesMap.get(newCase.OwnerId) + 1);
           System.debug('Number of cases for this owner has been incremented in the map' );
           System.debug('Number of cases for this owner: ' + userMap.get(newCase.OwnerId).Name + 'is: ' +ownerCasesMap.get(newCase.OwnerId));

       }

     }

      System.debug('Case has been inserted' );
  }
}
```

**Test class*:*

**Error Message**   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LimitCases: execution of BeforeInsert 
caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Trigger.LimitCases: line 5, column 1: []

**Stack Trace** Class.TestLimitCases1.testLimitCases1: line 49, column 1

Line 49 is where I do **insert newCase;**

Line 5, column 1 is **Integer maxNoCases   = Integer.valueof(maxCase.MaxCases__c);**

```
  @isTest
  public class TestLimitCases1 {
  static testMethod void testLimitCases1() {

//Principle #1: Create records from scratch

//1. Create the custom setting 

Max_Cases__c maxcasesetting = new Max_Cases__c();
maxcasesetting.MaxCases__c  = 10;
maxcasesetting.Name         = 'maxcases';
insert maxcasesetting;
System.debug('Max number of cases:' + maxcasesetting.MaxCases__c);

//2. Insert 1 user

User owner= new User();
owner.FirstName='mayak';
owner.LastName='vasatava';
owner.Alias = 'sriv123';
owner.UserName = 'randomguy@clearstructure.com';
owner.CommunityNickname = 'mangu';
owner.Email ='randomguy@gmail.com';
owner.ProfileId='00e80000000xDnf';
owner.TimeZoneSidKey    = 'GMT';
owner.LocaleSidKey      = 'en_US';
owner.EmailEncodingKey  = 'UTF-8';
owner.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';

  insert owner;

   System.debug('Inserted users Id is: ' + owner.Id);

  //3. Insert Case

   System.runas(owner) {

      Case newCase          = new Case();
      newCase.Subject       = 'Issue';
      newCase.Description   = 'Issue Description';
      newCase.Status        = 'Open';

  //  try {
      insert newCase;
   //   } catch (Exception e) {
    //      System.debug('Why is this happening?');
    //      }

   //Principle #2: Test things that should work

     Integer newCasesu1Count = [SELECT count() FROM Case];
     System.assertEquals(1, newCasesu1Count);


   //Principle #3: Test things that shouldn't work

      Case newCase1          = new Case();
      newCase1.Subject       = 'Issue';
      newCase1.Description   = 'Issue Description';
      newCase1.Status        = 'Open';

      insert newCase1;

      Integer newCount = [SELECT count() fROM Case];
      System.assertEquals(10, newCount);


  }

   }
 }
```

Comment: did you give an attempt by putting @isTest(SeeAllData=true) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the null pointer exception is from your custom setting. In your trigger, you have `maxcasesetting` as the setting name, while in the test class you are using `maxcases`. Change your test class to use `maxcasesetting` and it should work better.

Comment: Thank you Sire! I can't thank you enough for helping me with something that I had spent so much time on. Gracias!!

Comment: You're most welcome! You can use the 'tick' to 'accept' the answer, though there might be a minimum amount of time the question has to be open.